# How to bring data post ajax to Controller when redirect page

Tags: php, jquery

how to bring ajax post data to the controller when redirecting the page, I have got id_user data from `<a class="edit" href="<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/edit_user "?>" id_user="<?php echo $row ['idx'] ?>">Edit</a>` but when redirecting the data page is null / 0, how do I bring post ajax data to the redirect page through the controller, please help me, if something is unclear please apologize and can ask me ...

Note: I use PHP native MVC

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.edit').on('click', function(){
        var id_user =$(this).attr("id_user");
        alert(id_user);
        var url =$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: url,
            data:{id_user:id_user},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data)
            },
            error:function(err){
                alert(err)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my controller

```
public function edit(){

        Template::setTitle('Edit User Management');

        $id_user = (int)Request::post('id_user');

        $result = $this->getUserbyId($id_user);      

        $dataresult = json_decode($result, true);
        if($dataresult === NULL) {
            echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\No Have Data\");";
            echo "javascript:history.back();</script>";
            return false;
        }
        $data = $dataresult;
        return $data;
```

this is my code

```
<a class="edit" href="<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/edit "?>" id_user="<?php echo $row ['idx'] ?>">Edit</a>
```

this is my problem

I have get data id_user, I cacth data use alert 
[image]

but when I redirect page, this is result
[image]

I want to get data like this, when I redirect Page
[image]

This is my new error when I add Prevent Default
[image]

Comment: Use `Session` to store your temp data, or redirect with get params and check them in your controller. I think i gave you an idea how to get your data when you redirect.

Comment: A link is not a redirection and can't send variables via post unless you use some Javascript. I think the bes way is including user id in URL but you need to tell us how do you structure your links to grab values from URL.

Comment: can you tell us how to arrange the code? @Serghei Leonenco

Comment: first I get data from`<a class="edit" href="<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/edit_user "?>" id_user="<?php echo $row ['idx'] ?>">Edit</a>` , then I capture id_user data using jquery, I have got it, by the way I know through the id_user alert, then after I get the id_user data, I pass the data to the controller into a variable that can be used to call curl rest service, as soon as the flow can you help me? @Triby I have been deadlocked in 2 weeks to solve this problem

Comment: Your link is wrong, should be something like: **<a class="edit" href="<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/edit_user?id_user={$row ['idx']}"; ?>">Edit</a>**

Comment: same and show "undefined" @Triby

Comment: @Ren Why you not just assign an `GET` param to your `Edit` links and make it work like a url, after that just get this `param` in controller and do what you need to do? i just dont get what are you trying to get.

Comment: No, you must enclose array items between curly brackets to include them in and string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a list of rows and you render them somehow, you can assign an `id` of the record to each of the entity.

```
<a class="edit" href="<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/edit_user?id_user=" . $row['idx']; ?>">Edit</a>
```

Now, when you click, you make a GET request to your `edit` controller action with `id_user` parameter. You can handle this request like this:

```
public function edit_user(){

  if(isset($_GET['id_user'])){

    //TODO: make something with it
    var_dump($id_user);
    die();
  } else {
    //throw an error 
  }
}
```

And your JQuery code should looks like this:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(){
        var id_user =$(this).attr("id_user");
        alert(id_user);
        var url =$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: url,
            data:{id_user:id_user},
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
                window.location = '/app.php/usermanagement/edit_user?id_user=' + id_user;
            },
            error:function(err){
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING  in `<a class="edit" href="<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/edit_user?id_user=$row['idx']"; ?>">Edit</a>`

Comment: I have done what I have given, but show "unidentified " @Serghei Leonenco

Comment: What `undentified`? where it shows this error? at what point?

Comment: yess.. at point, I don't get data id_user....  @Serghei Leonenco

Comment: i write url like u give me answer, when I write again url like before I ask you, I add preventDefault(), but I get data and, my page edit_user.php show at alert, what your opinion, I will show my screenshoot above.. @Serghei Leonenco